# SSE reduce latency between server and client

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-sent-events

UPDATE: It seems that the whole thing is working, but has huge latencies.
My question is changed to "How to reduce the latency"

---

i currently have some trouble with a program utilizing PHP, HTML and Javascript to have a page brought up in the browser, which sends POSTs to the server, which sends SSE to the browser.
I've got 3 documents:
index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['send'] = False;
$_SESSION['counter'] = 0;

echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Server-Sent Events</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            var source = new EventSource("main.php");
            source.onmessage = function(event){
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Counter: " + event.data + "<br>";
            };
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function httpGetAsync(theUrl)
    {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl); 
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="httpGetAsync(\'http://localhost/click.php\')">Send</button>
    <div id="result">
        <!--Server response will be inserted here-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

click.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['send'] = True;
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
session_start();

// Send it in a message
while( 1 )
{
    if( $_SESSION['send'] == True )
    {
        $_SESSION['counter']+=1;
        echo "data: ".$_SESSION['counter']."\n\n";
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
        $_SESSION['send'] = False;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

The problem is that i don't receive any SSE Events.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You don't have ob_start and you forgot the keep alive header. It is not recommended to use SSE with Apache because it can use up too many threads if you have many SSE connections.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have decided to switch to Node.js thus eliminating Apache and SSE.